# Typescript: Can someone explain what's the square bracket [P] after {} does?

Tags: typescript

I was reading [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6-rc/) article about what's new in typescript 4.6 and I came across this weird syntax.

Could someone please explain what it does?

```js
type UnionRecord<P extends keyof TypeMap> = { [K in P]:
    {
        kind: K;
        v: TypeMap[K];
        f: (p: TypeMap[K]) => void;
    }
}[P];
```

The {}[P] : this [P] followed by the {}. Why is it there?

The full typescript code is given below.

```
interface TypeMap {
    "number": number;
    "string": string;
    "boolean": boolean;
}

type UnionRecord<P extends keyof TypeMap> = { [K in P]:
    {
        kind: K;
        v: TypeMap[K];
        f: (p: TypeMap[K]) => void;
    }
}[P];

function processRecord<K extends keyof TypeMap>(record: UnionRecord<K>) {
    return record.f(record.v);
}

processRecord({
    kind: "string",
    v: "hello!",

    // 'val' used to implicitly have the type 'string | number | boolean',
    // but now is correctly inferred to just 'string'.
    f: val => {
        console.log(val.toUpperCase());
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks to pointing me to this article btw., they improved some stuff I've been waiting for a long time now *-*

Comment: I've been using this amazing chrome extension name "dailydev" which gives a list of all popular blogs and articles to read. You can give it a shot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `[P]` you'd get a map with keys from `P`, in this example this would be a map with a subset of the keys "number", "string" and "boolean".

By adding an index lookup with the entire set of keys `P` this instead evaluates to a union type of all possible values for the given keys or explicit: `Inter["number"] | Inter["string"] | Inter["boolean"]` where

```
type Inter<P extends keyof TypeMap> = {
    [K in P]: {
        kind: K;
        v: TypeMap[K];
        f: (p: TypeMap[K]) => void;
    }
}
```

For another example consider:

```
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  active: boolean;
}

type UserFieldTypes = User[keyof User]
// UserFieldTypes is User['fistName'] | User['lastName'] | User['active']
// which equals string | string | boolean
```

Feel free to ask when there's still something unclear to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand it now.
by adding [p] after the object. the type will be the subset object instead of main/outer object.
```
type Inter<P extends keyof TypeMap> = {
    [K in P]: {
        kind: K;
        v: TypeMap[K];
        f: (p: TypeMap[K]) => void;
    }
}[P]
```
So adding [P] at the end I will get generic type Inter which will return be 
```type Inter = { kind:.., v:..., f:...}```